# Detect Keypress in background Linux in c/bash

Tags: linux, bash, background, keypress

I want to detect a key combination like alt+g in an application that runs as a background process (other keypresses/combinations should be executed normally) ,
 if the combination is pressed i want to block all keypresses and send them via serial to another linux pc instead of executing them. I cannot find a solution for detecting the key combination and recording the keys within a background process.

I'd prefer to use a  bash script, but c is ok aswell. 
I just cant find a starting point. Any directions or help are appreciated.

Comment: Do you care if it wants `sudo` rights?

Comment: GTK+ has tools for acquiring keyboard and mouse input. I am not sure if they work in the background, but it might be a place to start. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7696838/how-do-i-get-keyboard-and-mouse-input-in-gtk

Comment: By "background process" you mean the process of the shell?

Comment: I do not care if it wants sudo rights, by background process I mean a process that is started like this './example.sh &'

Comment: I think it's a typical case when it would be better to define the high-level problem first and then seek for a solution, as whatever is the root problem is, this sounds as a bad solution for it ;)

But you can use

`evtest /dev/input/by-path/platform-i8042-serio-0-event-kbd`

(you might need to adjust the file path), to read the keyboard events, and you can parse out the needed key shortcut.

Comment: I have two pc's, and I want to render a terminal like interface that displays my Input and either runs the commands I enter on the first or the second pc. The output of the command should then be rendered aswell. Basically a dumb terminal with one keyboard and two pc's.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Xlib I managed to fetch the keyboard Input http://www.x.org/releases/X11R7.7/doc/libX11/libX11/libX11.html

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't the application screen do what you want?  Allows you to detach & reattach to sessions on another PC over network (which could be connected over a serial line)?

[10 Screen command examples](http://www.tecmint.com/screen-command-examples-to-manage-linux-terminals/) and 
[How to use Linux Screen](https://www.rackaid.com/blog/linux-screen-tutorial-and-how-to/)